# jsp not loaded from jar file in weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, tomcat8

I am using spring boot 1.3.5.RELEASE.
I have many jsp in META-INF/resources/ of a jar file in my target.
When application is started by embed tomcat,this jsp files is detected and loaded but those isn't detected and loaded when application is started by weblogic 12.1.3.
this error is raised:

```
Index.jsp:14:19: The include file was not found.
    <%@ include file="/View/ScriptHeader/DateHead.jsp"%>
```

NOTE:extension of my package is .war

Comment: no any body to help me

Comment: with spring boot wyou should have a jar file, this jar file is what are yuou deploying as a war in weblogic ?